# Determining a mean and skewness of a probability density function

Tags: probability, random-variables

Is there any way to determine the mean and skewness of a probability density function WITHOUT integrating? 
I have the following function:
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x&\text{if}\ 0\le x\le1,\\
2-x&\text{if}\ 1\le x \le 2,\\
0&\text{elsewhere}.
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you need to determine the moments.

This PDF, however, is symmetric around the line $x = 1$, so the mean is $1$ and the skewness is $0$.

Comment: thanks for the reply! Makes it obvious once it's spelled out to me haha. Just one last quick question, if the shape wasn't symmetric, but still triangular in shape, would the tip (largest value) still be the mean? Obviously the skewness wouldn't be 0.

Comment: Not in general.  For instance, consider the PDF $f(x) = 2-2x, 0 \leq x \leq 1$, and $0$ otherwise.  The peak is at $(0, 2)$, but the mean is quite obviously not $0$.

Answer (score 1):

For this special example you can simply plot it and see that the mean is $1$ and the skewness is $0$.

**Note:** Skewness is a measure of asymmetry of the probability density function. Here your function is symmetric. So skewness is zero.

Refer to this link for more information:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness